# Will I be able to use sata 3 ssd with my current motherboard and if so will I be able to achieve reasonable performance gain

Tags: hard-drive, memory, ssd, motherboard, sata

Currently I am using [ASUS P5QPL-AM](https://www.asus.com/bd/Motherboards/P5QPLAM/specifications/) motherboard. This motherboard support the following storage system[image]

```
So my current hardware configuration is : 

motherboard : ASUS P5QPL-AM (ddr2)

ram : 4GB (ddr2)

storage : mechanical hard disc drive
```

I love computer programming and I am also a programmer by profession. For this reason I needed to run some CPU consuming tools and task which creates deadlock and thus decrease productivity and break mental concentration. Now I want to upgrade my pc on top of current configuration for faster experience.

**My Plan :** I would like to install an `internal 240 GB SATA-3 SSD`. In the SSD, I will install the operating system and all the other software tool which I will use.

Now I have the following questions :

1. As my current motherboard support `SATA-1` ([according to tech spec](https://www.asus.com/bd/Motherboards/P5QPLAM/specifications/)). If I install `SATA-3 SSD` in my pc, will my motherboard support it?
2. And if my motherboard support it, will it give me a reasonable fast experience along with my 4GB ram?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Given that you're a professional programmer earning professional programmer's wage, I'd seriously recommend upgrading to a computer that's not ancient. That motherboard is about 12-15 years old. DDR2 was old when I was a teenager.

Comment: I am going in that direction but I will do it gradually ,not all at once. This is my first pc and very dear to me. Can not discard it altogether. Sounds silly but that's the case

Answer (score 2, accepted):

3Gb/s is actually SATA II, not I

All SATA standards are backwardly compatibile to previous standards, but with limited bandwidth.

From [SanDisk® Global Customer Support](https://kb.sandisk.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/8142/%7E/difference-between-sata-i%2C-sata-ii-and-sata-iii)

> **Difference between SATA I, SATA II and SATA III**
> **What is the difference between SATA I, SATA II and SATA III?**
>
> SATA I (revision 1.x) interface, formally known as SATA 1.5Gb/s, is the first generation SATA interface running at 1.5 Gb/s. The bandwidth throughput, which is supported by the interface, is up to 150MB/s.
>
> SATA II (revision 2.x) interface, formally known as SATA 3Gb/s, is a second generation SATA interface running at 3.0 Gb/s. The bandwidth throughput, which is supported by the interface, is up to 300MB/s.
>
> SATA III (revision 3.x) interface, formally known as SATA 6Gb/s, is a third generation SATA interface running at 6.0Gb/s. The bandwidth throughput, which is supported by the interface, is up to 600MB/s. This interface is backwards compatible with SATA 3 Gb/s interface.
>
> SATA II specifications provide backward compatibility to function on SATA I ports. SATA III specifications provide backward compatibility to function on SATA I and SATA II ports. However, the maximum speed of the drive will be slower due to the lower speed limitations of the port.

Swapping an old spinny rust to an SSD, even at SATA II speeds will be night & day. The 4GB RAM is still going to be a bottleneck, though.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I got answer for my 1st question. I understand that all SATA versions are backward compatible but  SATA-3 will perform slower on SATA-1. But my second question is will I get a faster experience than my current situation if I install SATA-3 and install OS and other software tool?

Comment: Installed ssd to my system. Even with legacy bios and ddr2 system, I have seen significant performance improvement :)